# What European longsword schools use blades sharpened the entire length?

Tags: historic-european, longsword

I've been noticing a lot of interest in [ricasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricasso) work.  This makes sense when facing polearms, where you need more leverage — there's even a theory in Asian sword that the two handed sword techniques derive from rod technique, where the hands can be more widely spaced.

It feels dangerous and unnecessary against swords however, so I'm looking for European systems that don't teach grasping one's own blade *or* the opponent's blade.

- What European longsword systems use swords sharpened the entire length?

Video links are welcome, but an accepted answer should excerpt or cite written material, ideally historical manuals.